# Identifying Actors in Use Case Diagram for a mobile app

Tags: firebase, uml, use-case, use-case-diagram, magic-mirror

I have a system consisting of the following components:

- A mobile app that is controllable by users. Users can log in, create accounts, and then connect to a mirror and after that they can modify module settings and save the modifications.
- Firebase as the database and backend for the system.
- A REST API that controls a magic mirror. When a user is associated with it, the API requests JSON parameters from Firebase and applies them to the mirror. If there is no user associated, the mirror displays a QR code.

I tried this design:
[image]

I tried to make sense that the Main actor is the `User` and `Firebase` is the secondary one.  But it looks complex, and i'm not really sure of it, because in the end, the user only cares about changing the state of the smart mirror. As I am new to UML I'd like to know if this is the way to go?

Comment: Just throwing in a UC diagram is not enough. Where is your issue? Without context it's just guesswork. Anyway, see Chritophes answer which nails your real issue.

Comment: Thank you qwerty_so for replying, it's my bad to post a UC like that without any tables. I'm sorry because it's my first time interacting with UML so i am trying to get the basics. I read Christophe answer and it was really helpfull and made me somehow a clear idea.
I made an answer to Christophe that i guess is more clearer than what i have posted if you want to check it out.

Comment: You are on a better path now. UC are difficult for techies (I know what I'm talking of). If you want to get into the matter I recommend reading Bittner/Spence about use cases. The best read you can find (in my humble opinion).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I took a look at a preview and it seems really interesting. Thanks again!

Comment: Your question seems perfectly clear, and quite relevant in the area of mobile apps and smart devices. As it was closed, I added your comment at the end, to provide the focus that some readers were missing. I hope this is ok for you. Just for my understanding: is the smart mirror a smart device ? Is its purpose authentication or something else ?

Comment: There is no problem Christophe, on the contrary, i really appreciate what you have done.
For the Smart Mirror is just a device to display some usefull informations for the user, here is an [image](https://www.voiceinterconnect.de/files/public/inhalte/blog/Zauberspiegel_VIC.jpg) of it.
My app's intention is to let the user changes this information on the mirror according to what benefits him. When User get the smart mirror for the first time it will display a Qr code, using my app to scan it will let him connect to it and perform what i've told u before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the UML specifications:

> UseCases define the offered Behaviors of the subject **without reference to its internal structure**. These Behaviors, involving interactions between the Actors and the subject, may result in changes to the state of the subject and communications with its environment.

This means that as soon as you analyse use cases or actors based on the internal design of your system, you're on a wrong path.

Your use case should focus on the value added for the user, not on the technical solution:

> When a UseCase applies to a subject, it specifies a set of behaviors performed by that subject, which yields **an observable result that is of value for Actors** or other stakeholders of the subject.

Considering that actors can be system, how to check if `FireBase` is an actor?

- The first question is,  does it matter for the user.  Is the end user of your app interested in this candidate secondary actor?  Most probably, the end-user doesn't care.
- The second question is,  is the secondary actor independent,  and does it have a business purpose on its own that your system is helping to fulfil?
- The third question is,  could the secondary actor be switched to another secondary actor?

Firebase doesn't tick any of these boxes.  So it's probably a bad idea to go that way.

Comment: According to your answer, i should look out for what benefits the `user` and what is important to him. I read aswell about the `login` that it shouldn't be existed in a UseCase because it's an obstacle for the `user` and isn't something he essentially cares about.
With all of this information, the `user` only cares about changing the state of the `smart mirror` and i guess it should be a the secondary actor?
I am new to UML and I am doing my best to fully undrestand the concepts.
Thank you Christophe for your answer.

Comment: Yes, login is a heated debate: it has no added value taken independently, and is often a required step for something else.  It's more a constraint than a use-case. If the magic mirror is an independent, autonomous device, that could interact with other systems or apps as well,  you may consider it as a secondary actor.